# Under what condition on a set $S$ does $f$ exist such that $f \cdot S_k$ has the same value for all $S_k\in S$?

Tags: linear-algebra

this is my first time using this site so I apologize if I'm unclear or using poor convention.

I'm working on a problem with wireless power transfer, which long story short involves a set of transfer functions, which I will call **S**, which can be thought of a vector of length *n*. There are *k* such transfer functions. I want to pick a constant nontrivial frequency vector **f** of length *n* that will result in the same value for all transfer functions.

I believe the best way to write out this problem is:

Find $f$ such that $f \cdot S_k = C,  \forall k $, where $C$ is a constant.

I know this **f** exists for certain conditions of **S** because I have found it using a GA, but I am unsure how best to characterize this, or how to prove that a GA is required, if it is.

Under what conditions of **S** does an **f** exist that meets my conditions? After determining this my next step would be determining if **f** can be found analytically if **S** is known for all *k*.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is GA? genetic algorithm?

Comment: Correct, Genetic algorithm, sorry for not clarifying. It starts with a randomly generated vector of length n and maximizes the constant C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the following.

If I understood you right, I can formulate your question as follows. When for a given $n\times k $matrix $S=(S_1,\dots, S_k)^t$ there exists a vector $f$ such that $Sf=Ce$, where $e=(1,1,\dots, 1)$ and $C\ne 0$? Without loss of generality we may suppose that $C=1$. Then such a vector $f$ exists iff $\operatorname{rank} S=\operatorname{rank} (S|e)$, where $S|e$ is a matrix obtained from $S$ by concatenating the vector $e$ to the right side of $S$. And provided such a vector $f$ exists, you can find it analytically by solving a linear system $Sf=e$.

Comment: +1 for deciphering the question. But I think your conclusion is that a solution $f$ exists if the system specifying $f$ has a solution, which is not a great advance. But of course the fact that it is a linear system should make solving it not too impossible.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I worked with non mathematicians, which applied mathematics. And to solve their problem it was essentially to build a good and clear mathematical model of it. :-)

Comment: Thanks for you input, I am indeed a non mathematician and am looking for help formulating my question as much as a solution.

@Alex Ravsky: If I understand you correctly, the solution of $ Sf=e $ solving for f would give $ f = S^-1 e $ where $e$ is a $n$ length vector of 1s?

Comment: @user3838540 Not necessarily. The matrix $S$ may be degenerated (that is, $\det S=0$) or even not square, and then the matrix $S^{-1}$ does not exist.

Comment: Ah yes, $det(S) = 0$ would be a problem, which is a great constraint to look at. Perhaps a pseudo inverse method would be more efficient than my GA, maybe Neumann series would be appropriate, not that I'm familiar with those methods much but its a great direction to look at. Thanks!